# Can I install drivers that needs requires Windows 7 with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, drivers, acer-aspire

I've recently "revived" my old Acer  Aspire 7751, and since I'm broke, I couldn't install Windows 7, so I've installed a Windows 10 setup in my flashdrive. Anyways, I want to install new drivers but the only drivers there is, is for Windows 7 32 and 64 bit. This might be a long shot but I don't know. Thank you for reading this. Have a nice day/night.

Comment: Windows 10 will have most if not all of the drivers during installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no harm in trying.  While Acer may no longer provide Windows 10 drivers for their older hardware, that does not mean supported drivers are not available.  Remember, Acer didnt manufacture the graphics, sound, and network hardware, other companies did.  Acer just integrated them.  The Windows 10 installation will scan your hardware and warn you if any of the hardware is unsupported.  Windows 10 will typically install and run fine on most machines of the Windows 7 era.  Personally, I have yet to install Windows 10 on a machine that was designed for Windows 7, where it didnt have the drivers.  Even for Windows XP era machines, Windows 10 is fairly good about having supported drivers.  Unless your Acer uses some very obscure hardware, you should have no issues installing Windows 10.